# Cannot access HTTPS service from Docker container via Virtual Box

Tags: docker, tcp, virtualbox, portforwarding

I run a https web service from a docker container set up on Vbox. Here is my config:

**Vbox**

[image]

**Docker**

[image]

Unfortunatelly, `https://127.0.0.1` is not accessible.

The output of the command `docker run -it --rm --net=container:$cont_id --pid=container:$cont_id busybox netstat -lntp` is:

```
  Active Internet connections (only servers)
  Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21/sshd
  tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:444           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      319/node
  tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8081          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      315/python
  tcp        0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      21/sshd
  tcp        0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      319/node
```

I can't figure out where I'm getting wrong (I am still a beginner in port forwarding and networking). Any help appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the output of `docker run -it --rm --net=container:$cont_id --pid=container:$cont_id busybox netstat -lntp` using the id or name of your container (`$cont_id`) in your question?

Comment: Do you have a proxy set up on your browser?

Comment: Just added it @BMitch

Comment: From the docker host to the container and to the app itself look correct. Are you trying to connect with a browser/cli running inside of VirtualBox or outside on your parent OS? What error are you getting when you see the https is inaccessible?

Comment: @BMitch From a browser outside of VirtualBox, on my parent OS (precisely MacOS). Opening `https://127.0.0.1` outputs error message " “Safari can’t open the page because it can’t find the server”.

Comment: @naileakim And the ssh port is working  (`ssh USEROFTHEVM@localhost -p 2222`)? If not, try to specify both Host and Guest IP (`127.0.0.1`), and eventually restart the networking of the vm / restarting the vm

Comment: @Salem Yes I can ssh in the VM via `ssh root@localhost -p 2222` but not in the Docker container (that container runs on the VM).

Comment: In the output you posted the port is not right: `127.0.0.1:444`. Maybe something wrong in the script that starts the node server?